# Turn Google App Engine GqlQuery result into a Python dictionary

Tags: google-app-engine

How to turn an app engine GqlQuery into a dictionary, so that i can modify it, before turn it into JSON string?

Regards,

Johnny

p.s. I know there's a similar post, but the link suggested doesn't open any more.

Answer (score 1):

```
entities = YourKind.all().fetch(20)

dict_of_entities = dict((str(entity.key()), {'name': entity.name, 'size': entity.size}) for entity in entities)

# or

list_of_entities = [{'key': str(entity.key()),
                     'name': entity.name,
                     'size': entity.size} for entity in entities)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the low-level datastore interface found in google.appengine.api.datastore (and documented there, too). This provides an interface to the datastore that lets you work with dictionaries instead of models.